# Swagger naming issue with generics

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I want swagger to generate models seperately for generic sub models as shown in the example below:

```
public class TheModel<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GenericModel { get; set; }
}

public class GenericModel
{
}

public class AnotherGenericModel
{
}
```

Swagger generates the following schemas:

- GenericModel
- GenericModelTheModel
- AnotherGenericModel
- AnotherGenericModelTheModel

What I want the schemas to be:

- GenericModel
- TheModel<GenericModel>
- AnotherGenericModel
- TheModel<AnotherGenericModel>

I want to change the schemas created changed to the expected schemas.
Can this be done with Swashbuckle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved my own question and came up with the following solution shown below:

```
public class GenericFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        var type = context.Type;

        if (type.IsGenericType == false)
            return;

        schema.Title = $"{type.Name[0..^2]}<{type.GenericTypeArguments[0].Name}>";
    }
}
```

And add this to the Startup.cs `SwaggerGenOptions`

```
options.SchemaFilter<GenericFilter>();
```